# Retrieving messages over API/webhooks

Tags: api, rest, webhooks

I noticed that a few services such as AvivaIQ, AirGMS and Smartbnb have the ability to communicate with Airbnb's API (well before the announcement of the public API). They have the ability to notify you once someone makes a reservation, a booking etc.

I was wondering how have they been able to do this without an API, through webhooks?